# Rails: Creating a 'through' record in has-many-through relationship WITHOUT N+1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

This is super frustrating... I have a very simple `has_many :through` relationship with a `_type` field on the join table:

```
Subscriber
has_many :books
has_many :books, through: :selected_books

SelectedBook
belongs_to :book
belongs_to :subscriber
**_type** field

Book
has_many :selected_books
has_many :subscribers, through: :selected_books
```

I'm trying to create a `SelectedBook` with a specific type... I'm trying to create thousands of them actually.

I have an array of `book_ids` and the `subscriber_id`.

I want to do this...

```
  params[:book_ids].each do |book_id|
    current_user.selected_books.create!(_type: 'rental', book_id: book_id)
  end
```

Basically I want to insert all records as fast as possible (I don't need to instantiate it, and I don't need callbacks).

It keeps doing a stupid N+1 though for every single insert.

How can I just do 100 inserts (I'm trying to avoid raw SQL).

I solved it similarly like this in another part of my app:

```
@subscriber.regions << Region.where(id: params[:region_ids])
```

This works fine, because it does a single `SELECT * FROM regions WHERE id IN(1,2,3,4,5)`, so it's a single query.

The problem is, in this case I also need to insert an extra  `_type` column for the `SelectedBook`

Comment: If you don't mind a new dependency [`bulk_insert`](https://github.com/jamis/bulk_insert) to the rescue.

Comment: I looked at that but one of the open issues dissuaded me from using it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could do something like:

```
params[:book_ids].each do |book_id|
  SelectedBook.create!(_type: 'rental', book_id: book_id, subscriber_id: current_user.id)
end
```

BUT I would do a bulk insert... I know you are trying to avoid raw SQL, but it would generate a single SQL insert statement:

```
conn = ActiveRecord::Base.connection
inserts = []
params[:book_ids].each do |book_id|
  inserts << %{(
    #{conn.quote(book_id)},
    #{conn.quote(current_user.id)},
    #{conn.quote('rental')}
  )}
end
sql = %{
  INSERT INTO selected_books
  (book_id, subscriber_id, _type)
  VALUES #{inserts.join(',')}
}
conn.execute(sql)
```

Comment: The first way doesn't actually work, it tries to load everything. I've just given up and used raw SQL as you mentioned. Thanks